# Why doesn't Super User work without JavaScript?

Tags: support, javascript

Super User says it works best with JavaScript enabled. I would change that message to:

> Super User **does not** work without JavaScript.

Personally I dislike the JS layer, and switched it off, but then the post buttons no longer work. Can someone make the buttons work as normal HTML post buttons when JavaScript is turned off? That way the red message is more correct.

Strangely enough, the **Post New Question** button DOES work. Although you have to jump through a very complicated Human Being check. But the Answer buttons don't work.

Comment: Should be moved to metastack?

Comment: Apparently, then, Superuser DOES work better with Javascript, as advertised. Where's the problem?

Comment: I agree if a Q&A site doesn't let us answer without javascript, it basically **doesn't work** without it... but... Why would you want to disable JS anyway? Is there a good reason for that?

Answer (score 6):

I'm too lazy to search, but on one of the podcasts Jeff said something like this:

> When people turn off JavaScript, they have to accept that half the internet is broken for them.

That's quite true. Whether you find that good or not---it's a fact. While other sites might show some strange behavior with JS off, on the trilogy sites you at least get a warning. Asking and answering still works; if you want to go into more details of the site (voting etc.) there's no way around turning JS on, at least for the site in question.

And that's exactly what the message says: It work's best with JS on---but it somewhat works with JS off.

I don't disagree with your suggestion of a JavaScript-less fallback, but the message doesn't need correction.

Comment: @balpha: at work http://stackoverflow.com/ is allowed, but http://sstatic.net/ isn't. I can't answer nor vote. At work I regularly access blocked sites with http://translate.google.com/ that only works with plain content, doesn't act as a proxy for the JS files.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you "dislike the JS layer" when that layer makes the site work?

"I bought a new car which is really nice. However, I dislike the transmission and disabled it. Now the car isn't working any more. What gives?"

"My TV uses too much electrical power. I don't like that so I pulled the plug. Now the TV doesn't work. What should I do?"

Answer (score 1):

SU **does** work without JS. It allows you to answer questions WITH it, but searching and finding answers works fine. I see no issue with the warning thingy.